# Inheritance in ASP.Net Pages

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, inheritance

I am new to programming and just now am going through OOPs concepts when I learned about "inheritance" (the process of deriving a new class from an already existing class).

When I opened a new project in asp.net I found this,

```
public partial class Master_Pages_Email_Template : System.Web.UI.Page
{
```

which means the class is inherited from `page`?

When I tried to remove the `System.Web.UI.Page` some of the code showed errors (ex: `IsPostback`).

But when in inheritance when I need to access the methods or member variable from a parent class, I have to create a instance isn't it?

But without creating an instance how does this code work?

Sorry if I am wrong..

Comment: I can answer your question but it requires me to explain so many [object oriented terms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_object-oriented_programming_terms) like [Accessibility](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Member_visibility#Member_accessibility), etc.. I would suggest you to go through some of the basic OOP concepts and slowly you will start absorbing them on your own.

Comment: Thankyou,but it would be helpful if you throw some light...

Comment: Fine, I have written a simple answer if in case it is helpful to you

Comment: ASP.NET creates the instance for you when it is serving up the page in response to an HTTP request.

Answer (score 1):

When an instance of a derived class is created, an "instance" of the base class is created first. That is to say, the derived instance contains everything that would have been in a base instance. In fact, a derived instance *is a* instance of the base class.

Note that this is not specific to ASP.NET. ASP.NET pages are classes, so this is just normal OO.

Comment: So,without creating an instance how can we use all the properties and methods?

Comment: Creating an instance of the derived class creates an instance of the base class, basically.

Comment: yes,am clear about that,an instance of the derived class creates an instance of the base class too,but here, `public partial class Master_Pages_Email_Template : System.Web.UI.Page
{` we have no instance created,then how are we able to access properties like Postback

Comment: ASP.NET creates an instance for you during the page life cycle process

Answer (score 1):

If you are new to programming and OOP concepts then OOP has following main pillars.

```
 1. Inheritance
 2. encapsulation
 3. polymorphism
 4. Abstraction
```

You need to learn all these concepts in order to write any program in Object oriented way.

As far as your questions are concerned. Yes your class is inherited from page. and if you remove `System.Web.UI.Page` then you can't access method or properties of parent class. Because Inheritance is known as `IS A` relation.

So if you inherit `Class A` from `Class B` then you can access all method or properties of Class A in Class B. but do remember you can access properties or methods of parent class which are not defined as `Private` (Access Modifiers).

For details about OOP concepts please see. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173149.aspx

[To understans Access Modifiers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wxh6fsc7.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

When your class inherits from another class it gets all of the parent class's properties and methods and can use them as if they are its own, also can provide new implementation for these methods. You do not need to create an instance of the class in this case, instantiation is required only when you need to create an object of type class and to use its functionality... I would suggest you learn the basic C# clearly and then going for ASP.Net any such technologies because all of which are based on the base concepts..

PS: this guy got a good list of tutorials on these technologies..  http://www.youtube.com/user/kudvenkat/videos?flow=grid&view=1

Answer (score 0):

A simple code snippet to demonstrate [Inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_%28object-oriented_programming%29) and [Accessibility](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Member_visibility#Member_accessibility).

```
public class Base
{
    private int PrivateProperty { get; set; }
    protected int ProtectedProperty { get; set; }
    public bool PublicProperty { get; private set; }
}

public class Derived : Base
{
    public void A_Method_Which_Need_BaseProperties()
    {
        if (this.PublicProperty) //Derived can access (only Read) Base PublicProperty
        {
            this.ProtectedProperty = 1; //Derived can access (Both Read and Write) Base ProtectedProperty
            //this.PrivateProperty = 2; //You can't do this. Derived can not access Base PrivateProperty
        }
    }
}
```